# Javascript Recursion Array Variable

Tags: javascript

I've got a small bit of code I'm having a hell of a time with.

The function traverses through a data object successfully however I'm having trouble storing the results in a variable as the function calls itself and resets the variable.

```
function breadcrumb(data) {
    var results = new Array();
    for (var key in data) {
        // Ignore prototype
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        // Remove empty values
        if (data[key] === null) delete data[key];
        // Find only keys that match
        if (key === "parent_element") {
            var obj = data[key];
            console.log(data);
            results.push(data);
            // Traverse
            breadcrumb(obj);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
breadcrumb(data.wordpressPage);
```

The console log gives me the data I need. I've considered and looked at passing the variable from outside the function but haven't had any luck.

Any pointers as to how I can create a new object or array from the results of the function would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about `results.push(...breadcrumb(obj));` or `result = result.concat(breadcrumb(obj));` instead of `breadcrumb(obj);`? After all, `breadcrumb` returns your results. You’re not doing anything with this result by just calling the function. The scope of `var results` is limited to the current call.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the result as well as an argument to breadcrumb function when it is actually invoked. Modify the function parameters accordingly and return the result accordingly.

Comment: I think I had given something along the lines of your suggestion a go but couldn't get it working. The passed parameter was always undefined. .concat has resolved the issue.